# Caustic and Toxicological Determination

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, solubility, analytical-chemistry, solutions

**I need to determine whether or not a product that I am importing is "toxic" and or "corrosive" as defined below.** But I am a chemistry n00b — that is to say I have virtually zero experience with and or knowledge of chemistry — which is why I am here. I am hoping that one of you guys can help me out.

**Corrosive** is defined as being

1. capable of inducing necrosis or ulceration of epithelial
   tissue;
2. capable of causing an erythema or edema of the skin,
   corneal or iris damage or conjunctival swelling or redness; or
3. let us not worry about this right now.

**Toxic** is defined as being

1. capable of causing a lethal effect on a human;
2. capable of causing a serious and irreversible but non-lethal effect on a human, such as a depressed level of consciousness, muscular weakness or paralysis, acute renal or hepatic failure, arrhythmia, hypotension, dyspnea, respiratory depression, pulmonary edema or optic neuritis; or
3. let us not worry about this right now.

**Product Ingredients**

- Water
- Water-soluble vinyl acetate polymer
- Water-soluble natural wax
- Water-soluble silicone
- Natural glue

**Please let me know if any information is missing or any other information is required. Also, please feel free to tag or re-tag the question however you see fit.**

*Thanks in advance for any help whatsoever.*

Comment: @NilayGhosh no, i am not, but thanks anyways. i am trying to figure out whether or not the mixture is considered toxic and or corrosive according to the definitions that are provided.

Comment: @NilayGhosh i am too worried about the literal definition of corrosiveness, but rather the definition that i have provided in my question

Comment: As far as I can judge, your mixture is neither corrosive nor toxic. Water soluble vinyl acetate polymer is the scientific description of the popular paste, or white glue, that every pupil is using at school for  pasting images on sheets of paper. I don't know what is "Water-soluble natural wax", but it may be a sort of wax to make waxed paper or sealing. A silicone is a matter used to make water-proof joint or seal. The sum of all these stuffs should make a sort of cream or glue or anything similar which should not be corrosive or toxic.

Comment: @Maurice ohhh, wow, white glue. that was the one ingredient, that and the silicone, that worried me a little bit. thanks so much for your input. what i find weird is that, although water-soluble vinyl acetate polymer is white glue, the manufacturer also listed "natural glue" in the table of ingredients

Comment: Natural glue is probably a starch + water mixture. It may be used for stamps or for pasting labels on bottles.

Comment: @Maurice thanks. btw, you were indeed right that it is a liquid paste :)

Answer (score 2):

The way to get the information you seek is to obtain a [safety data sheet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_data_sheet) (SDS) for either your product or each of its ingredients.

Safety data sheets have slightly different content by jurisdiction, but most follow a common format, especially those that follow the [Globally Harmonized system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Harmonized_System_of_Classification_and_Labelling_of_Chemicals) (GHS).

In a SDS that follows the GHS, Section II identifies the hazards of the substance using tightly defined common phrases. If the product or one of its compounds is toxic in some way or corrosive, Section II will have that information.

Section II contains "Hazard Statements" and "Precautionary Statements". Here is a [SDS for acetic acid](http://www.labchem.com/tools/msds/msds/LC10100.pdf). There are three hazard statements:

- H226 - Flammable liquid and vapor
- H314 - Causes severe skin burns and eye damage
- H402 - Harmful to aquatic life

There are numerous precautionary statements. The Hazard statements provide the information you want. Here is a [list of GHS hazard statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GHS_hazard_statements).

Comment: i have the HS number of the good. i also have an SDS, although I am not sure how reliable it is since the specific regulations that are applicable in the country of origin are likely not applicable here. but its structure does seem to resemble that which is recommended by the GHS. however, the section 'Hazards Identification' simply states, "no special hazards", which seems especially vague lol. it certainly does not contain any GHS statements, so is that sufficient to conclude that it is neither corrosive or toxic according to the definitions above?

Comment: additionally, other than where it states "N/A" in the 'Toxicological Information' section, it states "Skin irritation acute: Direct contact may cause irritation" and "Eye irritation acute: Direct contact will cause irritation"